# How can I find 3 top or max value in django model?

Tags: python, django, backend

I have a class in django model and how can I find 3 maximum value in it? Do I need for into for loop? or Do I need any class?

```
class Prices (models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Price = models.IntegerField()
page = models.ManyToManyField(Listing_page,blank=True,related_name='Price')
def __str__(self) -> str:
    return f"{self.id} : {self.Price}"
```

I have follow code for top price but I need 3 top price too.

```
big_price = None

for num in post.Price.all():
    if (big_price is None or num.Price > big_price.Price):
        big_price = num
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a class in django model and how can I find 3 maximum value in it?

With a combination of [descending order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) (notice `-` in `"-Price"`) and [slicing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)

```
post.Price.all().order_by("-Price")[:3]
```

Comment: I appreciate for your response.

Answer (score 1):

You can order the queryset by price and then get the first 3 of them. It will give you what you need.Here is the link to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by)

So you can do:

```
Prices.objects.order_by("-Price")[:3]
```

Where `order_by` orders the queryset with the given fields value, `[:3]` limits it to 3 items.

Comment: `order_by` is ascending by default; your code will yield 3 lowest prices, which is not what OP wants.

Comment: Thanks, edited. But just saw you have almost exactly the same answer...

Comment: Yeah, there's not a lot of space for creativity in this case. :)